# Erro Slide Show Java Script

Tags: javascript

Então o meu slideshow só está funcionando a primeira imagem, as outras imagens não aparecem pra mim.

JAVASCRIPT

```js
{
  let satual = 1;
  let smax = 3;
  let stmp = 3000;

  function troca() {

    document.getElementById("e1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("e2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("e3").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("e" + satual).style.visibility = "visible";

    satual = satual + 1;

    if (satual > smax) {
      satual = 1;
    }
  }

  function slider() {

    document.getElementById("e1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("e2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("e3").style.visibility = "visible";

    sLiderTimer = setInterval(troca, stmp);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
 <title>Controla</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="slider()">

<div class="small"></div>

<div class="medium"></div>

<div class="large"></div>

<header id="cabecalho">
<div class="interface">
<img id="Logo" src="imagens/controla.png" style="width:350px; height:355px; margin-left: 51%;">
 </div>
</header>

<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Página Inicial</a></li>
  <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="Cadastro.php">Cadastrar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
    
<section id="banner">
    <div id="slider">
        <a id="e1" href="Cadastro.php"><img src="imagens/Imagem1.jpg"></a> 
        <img id="e2" src="imagens/Imagem2.jpg">
        <img id="e3" src="imagens/Imagem3.jpg">
    </div>
</section>
</body>
<footer id="sobrepg">    
<p> &copy; Controla Estoque 2018</p><br>

<h5 style="margin-left: -7.9em;position: relative;"> Um sistema de controle de estoque adequável para comercio de pequenas e microempresas, sendo padaria, pet shop, papelaria entre outros comércios existentes.</h5>
</footer>
```

```css
/*-------section---------*/
section
{
    background-color: #008153;
    padding: 6em 201px 30px;
    width: 78.1%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
     
}

/*-------slideshow--------*/
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#slider
{
    width: 842px;
    height: 312px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slider
{
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: O script parece funcionar normalmente. Teria que postar na pergunta o CSS pra poder ver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de utilizar `visibility` *hidden/visible*, use `display` *none/block*. O `visibility` *hidden* apenas torna o elemento invisível, mas ele continua ocupando espaço na página. Esta é a causa das outras imagens não aparecerem, pois ficam fora da área visível, ocupada apenas pela primeira imagem.

Substitua seu script por este:

```
let satual = 1;
let smax = 3;
let stmp = 3000;

function troca() {

   document.getElementById("e1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("e2").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("e3").style.display = "none";

   document.getElementById("e" + satual).style.display = "block";

   satual = satual + 1;

   if (satual > smax) {
      satual = 1;
   }
}

function slider() {

   document.getElementById("e1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("e2").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("e3").style.display = "block";

   sLiderTimer = setInterval(troca, stmp);
}
```